# Heads or Tails in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

The if and elif conditions aren't working and I am not even getting an error. The code is intended to match the users input to what the computer selects and then make a call, if the user won or lost.

```
import random

def flip():
    return random.choice(["Heads", "Tails"])


Users_Selection = (input("Choose: Heads or Tails?"))

print("Flipping the coin. Please wait!")


print ("It a", flip())


if flip()=="Heads" and "Heads"==Users_Selection:
        print("Congratulations, you won!")

elif flip()=="Tails" and "Tails"==Users_Selection:
        print("Sorry, You loose! Please try again")
```

All help is genuinely appreciated!

Comment: `"Heads"=="Users_Selection"` is never going to be true. I guess you meant `"Heads"==Users_Selection`

Comment: Tried editing that but still doesn't print the congratulations message

Comment: Note that you `flip()` two or three times during each run, it's not printing what it's actually comparing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you call flip, it generates a new random output so you must store the value of flip in a variable.

```
    c = flip()

    print("It's a ", c)


    if c=="Heads" and "Heads"==Users_Selection:
            print("Congratulations, you won!")

    elif c=="Tails" and "Tails"==Users_Selection:
            print("Sorry, You loose! Please try again")
```

Comment: There might still be a logic error. The user can never win if s/he selects "Tails". I think the `if` should be `if c == Users_Selection:` and the `elif` line should be replaced by a simple `else`.

Comment: Yes that is actually true!

Comment: import random

def flip():
    return random.choice(["Heads", "Tails"])



Users_Selection = (input("Choose: Heads or Tails?"))

print("Flipping the coin. Please wait!")


c = flip()

print("It's a, ", c)


if c=="Heads" and "Heads"==Users_Selection:
    print("Congratulations, you won!")

else:
    c=="Tails" and "Tails"==Users_Selection
    print("Sorry, You lose! Please try again")